# updating multiple rows at once with php

Tags: php, sql, variables, rows, updates

I retrieve multiple rows from one table and I display them in a grid.
For each row  I want to be able to change the name and then make one update that updates every row.
the grid looks something like this:
...

```
while ($rowsf=mysql_fetch_assoc($getrows)) {
$namelist=$rowsf['name'];
echo '<input name="nameupdate" type="text" value="'.htmlspecialchars($namelist, ENT_QUOTES).'"/><br>';
}
```

I currently have the following code, which would work if I had an array.
Is it possible to save each $nameupdate in an array?

```
 $nameupdate = $_POST['nameupdate'];
    $updateall=$_POST['updateall'];
        if ($updateall) {
        for($i=0; $i<=$maxpos; $i++) {
        mysql_query("update table set name='$nameupdate[$i]' where playlistid=$playlistget and pos=$i");
        }
        header("Location: mysite.php");
        }
```

What would be the best way to update the rows?

Answer (score 1):

To submit HTML data as an array to post.

```
echo '<input name="nameupdate[]" type="text" value="'.htmlspecialchars($namelist,     ENT_QUOTES).'"/><br>';
```

Then in the php side

```
$nameupdate = $_POST['nameupdate'];
foreach ($nameupdate as $name)
{
   // Update the Value
}
```

Comment: I want an array that has all $nameupdate values in it. Is this really all you have to do?